# List of Codec used in android?

Tags: android, codec

Hi i need to know everything about codec integration in android like list of codec with details and which one is best to use and how to use .(For audio and video call over internet )

Answer (score 0):

You can see all supported codecs at official documentation
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

In our calls project wich used WebRTC we using OPUS codec for audio and H264 for video.